# How accurate is numerical differentiation for high-order derivatives?

Tags: probability, derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Suppose you have a discrete probability distribution where the mass function $p$ is complicated and hard to compute, but the [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) $G$ is simple and easy to compute.  It is well-known that these two functions are related by:

$$p(k) = \frac{1}{k!} G^{(k)}(0).$$

Now, suppose you want to compute the mass function for some reasonably large value of $k$, but it is too difficult to get an analytic expression for the $k$th derivative of the probability generating function.  An obvious option is to fall back on numerical differentiation.  But how accurate is this, given that you need to compute a high-order derivative?  Given that there is some error in each step of the numerical differentiation, for large $k$, I imagine that this would blow the accuracy to pieces.

This kind of situation tends to occur when you are dealing with large sums of random variables, in cases where you can't rely on the central limit theorem.  For example, suppose you have a random variable $K = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ composed of $n$ independent (discrete) random variables.  In this case the mass function $p$ is a convolution of $n$ mass functions, so it is likely to be complicated and hard to compute.  However, the probability generating function is:

$$G(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n G_i(z).$$

Assuming that the individual generating functions $G_1,...,G_n$ are simple to compute, it will be simple to compute their product, and to it is simple to compute $G$.  Taking high-order derivatives becomes cumbersome, since the generating function is a product of a large number of functions.

---

**Question:** Generally speaking, using common mathematical/statistical software, how accurate is numerical differentiation for these kinds of high-order derivatives?  Are there any "order-based" results that would let me know if it is feasible to compute the mass values by this method?  How big could $k$ be before numerical differentiation would give a bad answer to this problem?

(**Note:** I am well aware that this answer depends on a range of factors, including the form of $G$ and the numerical procedure used, including the number of digits stored at each step.  In view of this, I am looking for any useful information on the feasibility of this computation method in realistic situations; feel free to fill in the blanks with any assumptions you need, as you see fit.)

Comment: Are finite difference approximations of your derivatives not suitable in your situation? Are Richardson's error estimates not reliable? How much differentiability do you have? How accurately can you compute the values of $G$?

Comment: I suppose those are all variable.  Is there a way to describe the accuracy of the computation relative to the accuracy of those parts?

Comment: Your question is very broad, to the point where I do not know where to begin. Can you narrow the scope a bit? In particular, what is a "realistic situation"? Do you mean to say, that the values of $G$ cannot be computed very accurately?

Comment: @CarlChristian: I have added an additional section setting out the general case where this happens, which is when you are dealing with large convolutions.  A realistic example would be when you have the sum of random variables that each have a simple parametric distribution, and they are independent, but not identically distributed.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this question? I have encountered precisely the same scenario myself!